# Opening two files one after another

Tags: c++

When trying to open two files one after another like this:

```
ofstream transactionFileList(file_day, std::ios_base::app);
transactionFileList << file_date << endl;
transactionFileList.close();


ofstream transactionFile(file_date);
for(int x = 0; x < _item_number_transaction.size(); x++){
    transactionFile << _item_number_transaction[x] << ":" << _quantity_transaction[x] << endl;
}
transactionFile.close();
```

I get no errors but only `transactionFileList` is being created.

Also when I `cout` `file_date` I get `13-04-1995.txt` so there are no problems with that variable! Any ideas?

---

### The variables

```
time_t t = time(0);
struct tm * now = localtime(&t);
char file_date[80];
char file_day[80];
strftime(file_date, 80, "%Y-%m-%d|%H:%M:%S.txt", now);
strftime(file_day, 80, "%Y-%m-%d_transactions.txt", now);
```

Comment: Hmm, what is the type of `file_day` and `file_date` ?

Comment: They are type `string`

Comment: Maybe `file_date` and `file_day` have the same value?

Comment: Please see my edit for how the variables are created

Comment: Which OS? file_data contains a pipe symbol and colons (which are not allowed in Windows filenames).

Comment: Thank you!!!! That was the problem!!

Comment: For the next time: Get the filename and "echo >> filename" in a console/terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_date` variable has invalid file name, so `transactionFile` is not opened, you can check it by condition:

```
if (transactionFile) {
    // do something with stream...
}
```

`file_date` contains symbol `|` that can't be used in file names in some OS.

I also suggest use power of RAII idiom and not call `close()` explicitly:

```
{
    ofstream transactionFile(file_date);
    if (transactionFile) {
        for(int x = 0; x < _item_number_transaction.size(); x++){
        transactionFile << _item_number_transaction[x] << ":" <<  _quantity_transaction[x] << endl;
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("File not opened.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are building `file_date` you get a special characters (`|:`)into it. It might be enough for the system not to allow the file creation.

For example in a windows shell I get :

C:\test>echo foo> a:2.txt
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable.

(French error message for `Path not found`).

AFAIK `:` is used to note *streams* into windows files (ref. in [Windows Dev Center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) Extract :

*Naming Conventions for Streams*

*When specified from the Windows shell command line, the full name of a stream is "filename:stream name:stream type", as in the following example: "myfile.dat:stream1:$DATA".*